# How to capture highlighted/selected text using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to be able to capture the highlighted portion of a text/string from an input field using AngularJS. I'm not really sure of where to start in tackling this problem.

For example, I have a textarea:

```
<textarea ng-model="input" placeholder="type your input">
```

How would I be able to capture the parts of the text that the user has highlighted or selected using his/her mouse pointer?

Comment: what do you mean by *capture*?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a directive that attaches to textarea and input elements events and monitors for the currently highlighted text. Something like

```js
var app = angular.module('module', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedText = '';
  $scope.textSelected = function(text){
    $scope.selectedText = text;
    $scope.$apply();
    //alert(text);
  };
});

app.directive('inputFieldSelection', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{
      onSelected: '='
    },
      link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
        elem.on('select', function(){ 
         var text = elem.val().substring(elem.prop('selectionStart'), 
              elem.prop('selectionEnd'));
          scope.onSelected(text); 
        });
        
        elem.on('blur', function(){ scope.onSelected('') });
        elem.on('keydown', function(){ scope.onSelected('')});
        elem.on('mousedown', function(){ scope.onSelected('')  });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="module">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <textarea input-field-selection on-selected="textSelected" type="text"></textarea>
          <p>{{selectedText}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.element('[ng-model="YOUR_MODEL_NAME_HERE"]').prop('selectionStart');
angular.element('[ng-model="YOUR_MODEL_NAME_HERE"]').prop('selectionEnd');
```

You can make use of 'selectionStart' and 'selectionEnd' to get the selection range. Hope this helps

Comment: Please add Working snippet to the answers